# blank window when lunching .exe produced by neutralino build release command

Tags: neutralinojs

I've tried **neutralino.js** ( javascript framework for building desktop application using web technos).

The first time i run the program , every thing work right. But after running the **neu build --release** and lunching the .exe file in **dist** folder, I ended up with a blank page.

Does anyone knows why?

Comment: Could you post your code and what framework you are using for the interface part? From the description it looks like your interface app just wasn't bundled to the .exe file

Answer (score 1):

Per documentation you want to run the command

CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -a -n="Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost_cw5n1h2txyewy"

as a super user
https://neutralino.js.org/docs/getting-started/your-first-neutralinojs-app/

The site also recommends that you install WebView2 Runtime for a better developer experience.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/#download-section